# Unaccent string in bash script (RHEL)

Tags: bash, iconv

On Debian-based distributions, there is a utility called **unaccent** which can be used to remove accents from accented letters in a text.

I was looking for a package containing this on Redhat distros, but the only one I found was [unac](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=unaccent) available for Mandriva only.

I tried to use [iconv](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/libiconv/documentation/libiconv-1.13/iconv.1.html) but it seems to not support my case.

What is the best, lightweight approach, easily usable in a bash script ?
Are there any secret options to iconv that allow this ?

Comment: [`unaccent`](http://www.nongnu.org/unac/unaccent-man1.en.html) doesn't *remove* accented characters, but "remove[s] accents from input stream or a string" ("été" is changed to "ete", not "t") - This is called [collation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collation). Do you really want to *remove* characters?

Comment: you are absolutely right, I want to remove accents, thanks for correction :) (I just fixed the question)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the `-c`(clear) option in `iconv` to remove non-ascii chars:

```
$ echo 'été' | iconv -c -f utf8 -t ascii
t
```

If you just want to remove the accent:

```
$ echo 'été' | iconv -f utf8 -t ascii//TRANSLIT
ete
```

Comment: Thanks, but as @l0b0 noticed, what I really wanted is to remove accents not accented chars. Is there a way to do this with iconv or any other tool ?

Comment: perfect, now it is what I needed, thanks - tested with {echo 'Příliš žluťoučký kůň úpěl ďábelské ódy' | iconv -t 'ASCII//TRANSLIT'}

Comment: Great solution; unfortunately, it doesn't work properly on OSX, presumably due to a bug (as of `OS X 10.9.2`, which comes with `GNU libiconv 1.11`): `echo 'ü' | iconv -f UTF8 -t ASCII//TRANSLIT` yields `"u` rather than `u`.